# ContextMenu (Popup) always on

Tags: javafx-2

I have a problem with a Context menu in JavaFx 2:it never disappers when I left click on the graph of the JFXPanel

Does anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Here is my code

```
 final ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
            MenuItem chartItem1 = new MenuItem("Chart Settings");

            cm.getItems().add(chartItem1);

            getScene().setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()  {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            if(cm.isShowing()){
                cm.hide();
            }
            if(mouseEvent.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY)
            {
                cm.show(getScene().getRoot(), mouseEvent.getScreenX(), mouseEvent.getScreenY());
            }
        }
    });
            chartItem1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                    dialogs.ChartFormat  cs = new dialogs.ChartFormat(null, true);                
                    cs.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    cs.setVisible(true);                
                }
              });
```

Comment: Can you please post some code to your question. I have made a demo app using the code in [this javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html) and added `ContextMenu` control to the scene. It is working for me with JavaFX 2.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproduced the described behavior. Don't know the reason but you can use `ContextMenu#hide()`:

```
final ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();  

MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("Item 1");
menuItem.addEventHandler(EventType.ROOT, new EventHandler<Event>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(Event t) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JPanel messagePane = new JPanel();
                    messagePane.add(new JLabel("label"));
                    JDialog jDialog = new JDialog();
                    jDialog.getContentPane().add(messagePane);
                    jDialog.pack();
                    jDialog.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
    });
cm.getItems().add(menuItem);

scene.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                // if(cm.isShowing())
                cm.hide();
                if (mouseEvent.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                    cm.show(lineChart, mouseEvent.getScreenX(), mouseEvent.getScreenY());
                }
            }
        });
```

Also you can check out these links:
http://pixelduke.wordpress.com/2011/12/11/popupmenu-in-javafx/
http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-17853
http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-14899

Adding sample code to your question would be more descriptive.

Comment: Thanks Uluk, your suggestion is working properly, but I still have a problem:
If I right click I can see the popup and with left click anywhere on the graph it disappears, so all fine.
My popup have an item, and by blicking on this item a JDialog appears, and here is the problem: when I click on this item in popup the dialog appears but popup still remains.

Comment: Updated the code and answer. When I click the MenuItem, the JDialog is showing up and the ContextMenu is disappeared. What version of javafx are you using?

Comment: I am using JavFX 2.0, NetBeans 7.1